# how to call a function in plsql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a plsql function and I want to call an other function from my function. how can I do this?

```
FUNCTION ortak_icra_job(prm_dosya_id             dosya.id%TYPE,
                     prm_aciklama             icra_hareket.aciklama%TYPE,
                     prm_kullanici_id         kullanici.id%TYPE,
                     prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi OUT NUMBER,
                     prm_hata_metni           OUT VARCHAR2,
                     prm_hata_kodu            OUT hata_mesaji.id%TYPE) 
BEGIN

askidan_indir(prm_dosya_id ,
               prm_aciklama ,
               prm_kullanici_id ,
               prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi ,
               prm_hata_metni ,
               prm_hata_kodu )

END;
```

is this correct way to do this ?

Comment: Your `FUNCTION ortak_icra_job` is missing a `RETURNS` declaration.

Comment: Also, you should avoid OUT parameters in a function - although it is allowed by the syntax, it's almost always better to use a procedure for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm) must return a value, else you should have an assignment target to the function.

```
FUNCTION ortak_icra_job(prm_dosya_id             dosya.id%TYPE,
                     prm_aciklama             icra_hareket.aciklama%TYPE,
                     prm_kullanici_id         kullanici.id%TYPE,
                     prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi OUT NUMBER,
                     prm_hata_metni           OUT VARCHAR2,
                     prm_hata_kodu            OUT hata_mesaji.id%TYPE) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR2 IS
v_result varchar2(200);
BEGIN

v_result := askidan_indir(prm_dosya_id ,
               prm_aciklama ,
               prm_kullanici_id ,
               prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi ,
               prm_hata_metni ,
               prm_hata_kodu );
RETURN v_result;
END;
```

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/exec_function.php) is an example how to run function. There are two ways to do that.

1. Try to add result value:

   ```
   result := askidan_indir(prm_dosya_id,
              prm_aciklama,
              prm_kullanici_id,
              prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi,
              prm_hata_metni,
              prm_hata_kodu )
   ```
2. You can also use your function in `select statement`:

   ```
   select askidan_indir(prm_dosya_id,
                    prm_aciklama,
                    prm_kullanici_id,
                    prm_ask_ind_kayit_sayisi,
                    prm_hata_metni,
                    prm_hata_kodu) 
   into result  
   from dual;
   ```

Comment: is it mandate that we need to have an LHS with out an RHS incase we are trying to call another function...