# Call PL\SQL via Java: Registering out parameter as boolean

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, boolean, callable-statement

I am calling a PL/SQL procedure in a Java application to update a database entry.

```
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement preparedCall = null;
Integer result = 0;
preparedCall = connection.prepareCall("{ ?= call pkg_temp.update_data(?, ?)}");
preparedCall.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN);
preparedCall.setString(2, variable1);
preparedCall.setString(3, cariable2);
result = preparedCall.executeUpdate();
```

But I am getting the below error at executeUpdate()

```
Severe: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The reason:PL\SQL not allows me to register to the type Boolean which is not a primary type.

How can I call this function?

Comment: At this thread you will find a answer for your question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890883/how-to-call-a-function-in-plsql-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890883/how-to-call-a-function-in-plsql-function)

Comment: sorry Rodrigo, I am a beginner in this and couldn't really understand the answer in the other thread.

Comment: Ok, so first of all, are you sure that the output type of your function is Boolean?

Comment: Booleans are a PL/SQL datatype and doesn’t exist in SQL. This means that when your PL/SQL function returns a boolean, you can’t use it in SQL.

Comment: this is the reason you are getting that error

Comment: but I am not allowed to change PL\SQL procedures given to me. I did some research and found that I have to write a wrapper  for the return value. But I do not understand how to do that?

Comment: are you allowed to create functions and procedures at the database?

Comment: no I am not...I can only change my java code

Comment: Ok... then try to change your `OracleTypes.BOOLEAN` to `OracleTypes.BIT` or `OracleTypes.VARCHAR`

Comment: And pray to works... If not, you will need to ask to your client create a wrapper of that function to retrieve INT (1 = TRUE | 0 = FALSE) or VARCHAR ('TRUE' | 'FALSE')

Comment: thanks Roger..but OracleTypes.BIT or OracleTypes.VARCHAR are not working.

Answer (score 2):

Finally managed to write a wrapper to take the boolean and return an Integer like this.

```
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement preparedCall = null;
Integer result = 0;
preparedCall = connection.prepareCall(
                    "BEGIN " +
                    " ?:= CASE pkg_temp.update_data(?, ?) "+
                    " WHEN TRUE THEN 1 " +  " ELSE 0 " +
                    " END; " +
                    "END; "
                    );
preparedCall.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
preparedCall.setString(2, variable1);
preparedCall.setString(3, variable2);
result = preparedCall.executeUpdate();
int funcRetValue = preparedCall.getInt(1);
if (funcRetValue == 1) {
    retValue = true;
} else {
    retValue = false;
}
```