# Ignoring a PL/SQL function's return value

Tags: oracle, plsql

Sometimes I call a PL/SQL function to receive and process the value it returns. Other times I would like to call the same function for its side effects only.

For example, consider a logging function that logs its arguments in a table, and subsequently returns a formatted string created out of the same arguments. Sometimes I'd like to use the returned value, e.g. to display it to the user, other times I just call the function for the table logging and ignore the return value. In the latter case I'd like to avoid declaring a variable to hold the returned value and write an assigment statement.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890883/how-to-call-a-function-in-plsql-function) touches the subject, and the answer seems to be that the caller must consume the value returned by the function, be it via an assignment statement or `select into`.

Is there a way to call a function in PL/SQL and discard the returned value?

Comment: Why do you care? If you have to call it for some reason, do it. The simplest way is to assign it to a variable. If you don't do anything with it later, so what? In other words, I don't understand your concern (apart from the fact that you'd like to avoid declaring the variable).

Comment: To me, assigning a variable and then doing nothing with it is a code smell, as opposed to calling a function that is known to have desirable side effects, and ignoring its return value.

Comment: @waldrumpus
Huge part of design of plsql results in code smells and you have to get used to it.

Only way to mitigate it here is to declare small anonymous block like declare x number; begin x := func(); end; Yes, it is ugly, but at least the unused variable doesn't polute outer scope.

Comment: @piezol - *"Huge part of design of plsql results in code smells"* - I think what you mean is idiomatic PL/SQL is different from idiomatic Java (or whatever your yardstick is). A lot of so-called smells are actually attempts to fit inappropriate paradigms to PL/SQL.

Comment: @APC I think you hit the nail on the head here. I have been tasked with implementing a process with lots of moving parts, and all of the control logic has to be realized in PL/SQL as well. This question stems from my attempts to solve this with the means I am used to - probably resulting in some inappropriate uses of PL/SQL.

Comment: Then break your function into its component parts. A procedure to create the log and a function to format and return a message. As it is your function performs 2 tasks.

Comment: @Belayer - yes, but for the function to retrieve the formatted message you'd need to pass in the message ID (or something), and that ID would have to be returned by the procedure which creates the log. So that implementation doesn't solve the OP's problem, unlike [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709352/146325).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> assigning a variable and then doing nothing with it is a code smell

If we're talking code smells, having a function which changes database state is a bit whiffy. The convention is that procedures change state and functions only read state.

So, to take your example, you could implement your logging function as two overloaded procedures in a logger package.

```
procedure log_this(p1_in number, p2 in timestamp, p_fmt_txt out varchar2);

procedure log_this(p1_in number, p2 in timestamp);
```

In the package body the second procedure just calls the first procedure and swallows the out parameter.

Now you can call the appropriate procedure, depending on whether you want to see the formatted string.

Of course, this solution won't work if you want to call your function in a SELECT statement, but changing database state through a query really is a code smell.

Comment: That is a great idea that hadn't occurred to me yet.

Comment: @waldrumpus - not everybody likes overloading, but I think used carefully it can be a tremendous boon.

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that it's not possible to ignore a function return value, there are some workarounds that do not require a dummy variable, which the original poster seemed to want to avoid. For example, I just had an example where a function returns a BOOLEAN and I want to evaluate that in some cases, but not in others.
So I used:

```
IF function(x) OR TRUE THEN ... END IF;
```

For other return types, you could use

```
IF function(x) IS NOT NULL OR TRUE ... END IF;
```

Not great, but shorter than creating and assigning a dummy variable.